# Duplicate rows on insert in Firebird DB and Python

Tags: firebird

I have a database with a DDL like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table(
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    COLUMN1 VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

and with ID autoincrementing on insert like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER table_BI FOR table BEFORE INSERT AS
BEGIN
  NEW.ID = GEN_ID(generator, 1);
END
```

My problem is when I add a new row with the same value in the `column1` as in an already existing row I get two rows with the same values but different ID.

Comment: you can use `MERGE` with `SELECT ..... FROM RDB$DATABASE` for the source. You can also `CREATe UNIQUE INDEX` on `column1` field and let the database fail insertion. But the problem itsels feels weird, there maybe is something shady with workflow and application design. Let your program doe not do inserting record, if there already exists record which fits. Make program logic like that: Function NeedUser(name): database-row-or-id; Begin: if (select id where column1= :name) then return id else return (insert into table(column1) values(name) returning ID);

Comment: Thank you, the `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX` solved it. Now an error is coming from firebird itself.

Comment: Notice that SQL has difference between `primary key` and `unique indexes` w.r.t. NULLS - PK prohibits NULLs, while UIx allows them, and there is reasonable in retrospect but somewhat convoluted rules on NULLS in multi-column Unique Indices. Read Firebird documentaiton about NULLs in Unique Index.